# QTransform().rotate() changes the position of the widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a QGraphicsView with a QGraphicsScene which has an added QPixmap.

I want to draw a rectangle onto the screen and rotate it by 75deg or any other.

However, i tried the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QMainWindow , QWidget , QLabel
import sys

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    window = QMainWindow()
    
    graphics = QGraphicsView(window)
    
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    
    scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("new_image.png"))
    
    graphics.setScene(scene)
    
    graphics.setGeometry(QRect(0 , 0 , 1980 , 1080))
    
    graphics.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
    
    rect = scene.addRect(700 , 10 , 100 , 50)
    
    rect.setTransform(QTransform().rotate(75))

    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

which does rotate the label, but changes it's position. On commenting the rotate line, It is positioned in the correct position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems and misconceptions in your code.

1. arbitrarily adding widgets and setting fixed geometries is discouraged, as [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) should be used instead;
2. widgets should not be added to a QMainWindow just by parenting them to it, but by setting them as their [central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework); the central widget is installed in the internal layout manager of the QMainWindow using [`setCentralWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#setCentralWidget);
3. a QGraphicsView automatically sets the visible/scrollable [`scene rectangle`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#sceneRect-prop) based on the bounding rectangle of the contents of that scene;
4. items are *always* created with a [position](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#pos) of `0,0`; a QGraphicsRectItem created with `100, 100, 50, 50` will add an item *positioned* at `0,0` with the `50x50` rectangle drawn at `100,100`;
5. transformations (including rotations) always default to the [`origin point`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#transformOriginPoint) of `0,0`;
6. `setTransform` is applied to the *current* transformation and doesn't consider the transform origin point; if you want to rotate the item, use [`setRotation()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation);

Considering the above, if you want a rectangle *placed* at `700,10` that is rotated by 75 degrees around its origin point, you should add a QGraphicsRectItem with coordinates `0, 0, 100, 50` and *moved* at `700,10`. Note that, as said, the transformation origin is always at `0,0` and `setTransform` ignores that, so if you want to rotate it around its center, you should set that point too:

```
    rect = scene.addRect(0, 0, 100, 50)
    rect.setPos(700, 10)
    rect.setTransformOriginPoint(rect.boundingRect().center())
    rect.setRotation(75)
```

This is a proper correction of your code, including all aspects explained above:

```
def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    graphics = QGraphicsView()
    window.setCentralWidget(graphics)
    scene = QGraphicsScene()
    scene.addPixmap(QPixmap("new_image.png"))
    graphics.setScene(scene)
    graphics.setSceneRect(QRectF(0 , 0 , 1980 , 1080))
    graphics.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
    rect = scene.addRect(0, 0, 100, 50)
    rect.setPos(700, 10)
    rect.setTransformOriginPoint(rect.boundingRect().center())
    rect.setRotation(75)
    window.show()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I didn't add the central widget as it was a part of my code. And, i used setRotation() as well, but got the same result.

Comment: However, can i add animation on changing the rotation. Like using QPropertyAnimation(myRect , b"rotation")?

Comment: @0xsapphir3 1. whenever you provide an example code, you must always ensure it is a *proper* example: we cannot know if you just left out some parts or if that is actually your normal "practice", and other people might take that code as a proper way of creating a basic example (which is not); crafting a good example code can even take hours, and that's what a good question is made of; 2. if you did use `setRotation()` and it didn't work, then you did something wrong (probably missed the part about the default position);

Comment: 3. I don't know who downvoted, and you shouldn't consider it as a "personal offense": voting is just a mean to highlight quality posts, not to "punish" somebody. 4. QPropertyAnimation only works on classes based on QObject (and QGraphicsRectItem is not); you either use a basic QVariantAnimation, or a QGraphicsObject with a child QGraphicsRectItem, then implement `paint()` with a basic `pass` and `boundingRect()` returning `self.childrenBoundingRect()`; if you need further help on that, I suggest you to do research about the above, and create another question, as it's off topic for this post.

Comment: Note about point 3: I also got a DV for my answer, and I sincerely don't care *that* much: I can understand that somebody could not agree with what I've written, or that I pointed out aspects that are not so relevant to the matter at hand, or even that my writing might seem paternalizing; I can consider all of the above for my future posts as I've always done, while also remembering that some people downvotes "just because" (sometimes it happens, just deal with it). That said, to your own admission, you didn't put enough effort to craft a good example, and that often brings down votes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235501/discussion-between-0xsapphir3-and-musicamante).